# Docker python api with auto_remove=True doesn't return stdout

Tags: python, docker

I need the auto_remove=True option instead of remove=True to have a more robust deletion mechanism. However, the following code doesn't allow me to get the stdout:

```
import docker

client = docker.from_env()

container_options = {
    'image': 'age',
    'command': ["sh", "/predictAge.sh", "2"],
    'auto_remove': True,
    'detach': True,
    'stderr':True,
    'stdout':True
}

container = client.containers.run(**container_options)
stdout_bytes = container.logs(stdout=True, stderr=False)
stdout_str = stdout_bytes.decode('utf-8')
print(stdout_str)
```

It seems like the container is removed before one can grab the stdout:

```
    raise cls(e, response=response, explanation=explanation) from e
docker.errors.NotFound: 404 Client Error for http+docker://localhost/v1.43/containers/1da46e6a02d621ed01ed38063aea75cf43b2806246430bdffd312567fea90738/json: Not Found ("No such container: 1da46e6a02d621ed01ed38063aea75cf43b2806246430bdffd312567fea90738")
```

How can I use auto_remove=True but at the same time get the stdout?

---

### Update

A generic code which still generates the error for testing:

```
import docker

client = docker.from_env()

container_options = {
    'image': 'hello-world',
    'auto_remove': True,
    'stdout':True
}

container = client.containers.run(**container_options)
stdout_bytes = container.logs(stdout=True, stderr=False)
stdout_str = stdout_bytes.decode('utf-8')
print(stdout_str)
```

Comment: If you detach from the container there will be no output shown.

Comment: Thanks @KlausD. but with 'detach': False it is the same

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't set both `auto_remove` and `detach` to true.  This is the equivalent of providing both `docker run -d --rm` options.  When the main container process finishes, the container is immediately deleted, along with its temporary filesystem but also along with its logs.

If you don't specify `detach`, then [`client.containers.run()`](https://docker-py.readthedocs.io/en/stable/containers.html#docker.models.containers.ContainerCollection.run) will directly return the container's output:

```py
stdout_bytes = client.containers.run(image='age',
  command=['/predictAge.sh', '2'],
  auto_remove=True,
  stdout=True)
```

If you need the `Container` object, or if you want to do other work while the container is running, then you can't specify `auto_remove` (and yes, under some circumstances, it's possible you'll leak the container).

```py
container = client.containers.run(image='age',
  command=['/predictAge.sh', '2'],
  detach=True,
  stdout=True)
...
container.wait()
stdout_bytes = container.logs(stdout=True, stderr=False)
container.remove()
```

Comment: Thanks, I thought it would work exactly like this (with auto_remove=True) and I tried it before since it is the most logical but I get the same error: ocker.errors.NotFound: 404 Client Error for http+docker://localhost/v1.43/containers/1f323b63db5620b6d7a2a3b055f5e4092dbad28a635b99bdd26590fe7b582d5c/json: Not Found ("No such container: 1f323b63db5620b6d7a2a3b055f5e4092dbad28a635b99bdd26590fe7b582d5c"). With auto_remove=False it works but then I have to manually delete it

Comment: please see above a generic example based on your suggestion still generating the error